# Link from an HTML file to a view

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have an HTML file that's loaded from a UIWebView. I'm looking to do the opposite - link from the HTML file to a different view controller. How would one go about doing this?

the html file is a local file within the app.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adopting `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and implement the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method. Here you can capture all requests and selectively use them for your purpose.

Define links such as `yourapp://yourviewcontroller/argument` within the HTML page and parse them in the above mentioned delegate method and load the appropriate view controller.

Answer (score 1):

try using three20 library

> https://github.com/facebook/three20

there is a helpful class for this named TTStyledText which render html as well as custom links. just need to map the links with ur controller. Go through the samples in three20!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short answer, but there are a lot of parts to this. Check out this link.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=463491

It looks like you might have to register the url with Apple. I know that for the maps application its able to do urls like `map://...` and I've seen other apps do it too, I just don't know the exact process.

---

Update: looks like this [exampe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LaunchMe/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple should help.

Comment: thanks for your response. just to clarify: the html file is a local file within the app. I don't need a website to launch my app from Safari. I just want an html link from an html file that's been loaded in a UIWebView to link to another view.

Comment: I think it should act the same way, but I could be wrong. Also looks like there are hacks to get JavaScript to call your code [link](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/calling-objective-c-from-javascript-in-an-iphone-uiwebview/)